# What is the name of those ports circled in red please?

Tags: rf, connector, antenna

[image]

I know those ports are u.fl but I am not what they are they and where can I find cables that plugs into them and have SMA connector on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Ports? Do you mean "connectors"?

I don't know what port they are because you did not say what that board is.

But I think I know what connector they are: very likely U.FL.

> where can I find cables that plugs into them and have SMA connector on the other end.

https://www.google.com/search?q=u.fl+to+sma+cable

Comment: To add to this: they are not just ufl connectors, they are switching ufl connectors. This means that when nothing is connected, they let the signal through (to the antenna), but when you attach a cable to the connector, it switches the signal so it goes through the cable and does not reach the antenna

Answer (score 0):

They are switching u.FL connectors.

You don't say what the board is, but from the PCB I can see each is associated with an antenna on the PCB. When connected the PCB antenna would be disconnected, and the signal routed to the cable.

I would therefore assume they are either for external antenna connections, or for testing during production.

Comment: Given that this is a ubiquity board, is this WiFi access point, to which you want to connect external antenna?